# A pythonic way for values comparison in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, rows

The problem:

1. The input is a tab delimited file. The rows are variables and the columns are samples. Variables can assume three values (00,01,11), and are listed in an order that needs to be mantained (v1->vN). There are large numbers of rows and columns, so the input file needs to be read in blocks.

   The input looks like this:

   ```
      s1 s2 s3 s4
   v1 00 00 11 01
   v2 00 00 00 00
   v3 01 11 00 00
   v4 00 00 00 00
   (...)
   ```
2. What I am trying to do is split the input into pieces of several rows, where the pieces are just big enough that the samples are each unique. In the above example, starting from v1, the first block should end at v3, as there is enough information at that point that the samples are unique. The next block will start at v4 and repeat the process. The task ends when the last row is reached. The blocks shall be printed in an output file.

---

My attempt:

What i was trying to do is to use csv module to produce an array composed by lists each containing  the states of a single variable (00,01,00) for all samples. OR, by pivoting the input, creating lists containing samples states for each variable. I'm asking whether the work should be focused on columns or on rows, *ie* if is better to use v1=['00','00','11','01'] or s1=['00','00','01','00',...]

The following code refers to the pivoting operation by which I tried to change the column-problem into a row-problem.
(Sorry for the clumsy python syntax, is the best I could do)

```
my_infilename='my_file.txt'
csv_infile=csv.reader(open(my_infilename,'r'), delimiter='\t')
out=open('transposed_'+my_infilename, 'w')
csv_infile=zip(*csv_infile)
line_n=0
for line in csv_infile:
line_n+=1
    if line_n==1:    #headers
        continue
    else:
        line=(','.join(line)+'\n')  #just to make it readable to me
        out.write(line)
out.close()
```

What is the best way to approach this problem? Can pivoting be of any help? Is there any built-in function I can rely on?

Comment: Basically how to put down a script with a loop which would permit me to identify the minimum amount of ordered variables necessary to distinguish each sample.

Comment: How does that relate to the code you posted? What part of this problem is problematic? Right now, this post sounds like "I tried to solve this problem, but can't, so can you do it?"

Comment: The code I posted should give an idea of how far I went, proposing the pivoting as a possible approach. I'm not asking for a script or for somebody solving the problem for me, I'm asking for some insights that evidently I didn't find elsewhere.

Comment: You don't need to convince me. The fact is that you have no answers on this, and three close votes. I strongly suggest that you update your question, and break down your dense paragraphs.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Describe exactly, step-by-step, what you're trying to do. What does "find the minimum number of subsequent variables necessary to univocally determine all the samples" mean? I know all of those words, but the meaning of the whole eludes me.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the insights. I really hope the post is clearer now.

Comment: @agf I followed your suggestion. Hope it is ok now. Sorry for the messy exposition, I'll try to be better from now on ;)

Comment: @cometarossa Better. I understand your problem. I changed your post a bit to be even more clear, but while the answer below seems inefficient and overly complex, it also looks like it could be correct. Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @agf Just to say the method works ok. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you get the csv data imported as a list of lists that are all the same length, how does this work for you ...

```
def get_block(data_rows):
    samples = []

    for cell in data_rows[0]:
        samples.append('')

    # add one row at a time to each sample and see if all are unique
    for row_index, row in enumerate(data_rows):
        for cell_index, cell in enumerate(row):
            samples[cell_index] = '%s%s' % (samples[cell_index], cell)

        are_all_unique = True
        sample_dict = {} # use dictionary keys to find repeats
        for sample in samples:
            if sample_dict.get(sample):
                # already there, so another row needed
                are_all_unique = False
                break
            sample_dict[sample] = True # add the key to the dictionary
        if are_all_unique:
            return True, row_index

    return False, None

def get_all_blocks(all_rows):
    remaining_rows = all_rows[:] # make a copy    
    blocks = []

    while True:
        found_block, block_end_index = get_block(remaining_rows)
        if found_block:
            blocks.append(remaining_rows[:block_end_index+1])
            remaining_rows = remaining_rows[block_end_index+1:]
            if not remaining_rows:
                break
        else:
            blocks.append(remaining_rows[:])
            break

    return blocks


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = ['00', '00', '11', '01']
    v2 = ['00', '00', '00', '00']
    v3 = ['01', '11', '00', '00']
    v4 = ['00', '00', '00', '00']

    all_rows = [v1, v2, v3, v4]

    blocks = get_all_blocks(all_rows)

    for index, block in enumerate(blocks):
        print "This is block %s." % index
        for row in block:
            print row
        print
```

=================

This is block 0.

['00', '00', '11', '01']

['00', '00', '00', '00']

['01', '11', '00', '00']

This is block 1.

['00', '00', '00', '00']

Comment: It looks exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help, I'll let you know as soon as I try it.

Comment: Works marvel. I'd give you a vote up, but my reputation is too low!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem at all ("ordinated variables"? "univocally determine a sample"?), but I know that you are using the csv module incorrectly and your indentation is incorrect too.

I don't know exactly what you input file looks like, but assuming it's tab-delimited, the following (untested) script shows one way you would go about taking blocks from your input file, turning them, and rewriting to your output file.

```py
import csv

# this is not strictly necessary, but you can define a custom dialect for input and output

class SampleDialect (csv.Dialect):
    delimiter = "\t"
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE    

sampledialect = SampleDialect()

ifn = 'my_file.txt'
ofn = 'transposed_'+ifn

ifp = open(ifn, 'rb')
ofp = open(ofn, 'wb')

incsv = csv.reader(ifp, dialect=sampledialect)
outcsv = csv.writer(ofp, dialect=sampledialect)


header = None
block = []
for lineno, samples in enumerate(incsv):
    if lineno==0: #header
        header = samples
        continue
    block.append(samples)
    if lineno%3:
        # end of block
        # do something with block
        # then write it out
        outcsv.writerows(block)
        block = []

ifp.close()
ofp.close()
```

Comment: The blocks aren't all the same size. He wanted each block to have just enough rows for each column to be unique from the other samples in the block.

Comment: I was more demonstrating the use of csv readers and writers. He will have to change the `if lineno%3:` line to whatever his condition is.